# JFace: TreeViewer with two icons or larger icon

Tags: java, eclipse, treeview, icons, jface

is there a way to assign an icon with the size of 32*16 instead of 16*16 to a treeviewer item? Another way would be to add two icon side by side at an item. 
Like the CheckboxTreeViewer, which has also two Icons (the checkbox and the item icon) side by side.

Has anyone an Idea how to do this?

Cheers,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

If you use a label provider derived from `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.OwnerDrawLabelProvider` you can draw whatever you like in the rows.

`OwnerDrawLabelProvider` requires you to erase, measure and paint each row yourself using `GC` based operations.

It supports tool tips through `getToolTipText(Object)` (also tool tip fonts, color, time out).

Comment: At the moment I'm using a ColorProvider. So I've completely change to OwnerDrawLabelProvider? Will it work in the same way like the normal labelprovider (getImage, getText..)? And will it support Tooltips?

Comment: Hmm, painting all by myself sounds like a lot of work, so this isn't then really an option for me. I'm wondering that there is no native support for TreeViewers..